# Facebook ignoring og:image for shared website link

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have recently noticed that facebook has started ignoring my og:image tag on my site. The image used is always larger than 200x200.

Here is an example page:

<del>http://bit.ly/15CrOhS</del>

http://bit.ly/1b8Mgbe

Seems to be alot of questions, but no answers. I've added all the og information and checked with the linter and it all goes through fine. So why does it choose to pick a random image?

I use the facebook api for PHP to send:

```
<?php

$link = 'http://www.mylinkaddress.com';
$msg = 'Check out my new photo. '.$link;

$get_oauth = "SELECT * FROM users_oauth_cred WHERE userid = ".$_SESSION['userid']." AND share = 1 AND oauth_access_token != ''";
$get_oauth = mysql_query_run($get_oauth);
$oauth = mysql_fetch_array($get_oauth);

# FACEBOOK
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => FACEBOOKAPPID,
    'secret' => FACEBOOKSECRET,
    'cookie' => false,
));
$token = $oauth['oauth_access_token'];

try {
    $result = $facebook->api(
            '/me/feed/',
            'post',
            array('access_token' => $token, 'message' => str_replace($link,'',$msg), 'link' => $link)
    );

}
catch(FacebookApiException $e) {}

?>
```

Comment: Could you please try and force a re-scrape of your link as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/#update

Comment: @CBroe I've been posting new links for testing and the image is still wrong.

Comment: And you’re sure you are not setting the `picture` parameter while making your API call for posting? / Is it a different image each time?

Comment: @CBroe Positive. Facebook seems to like a particular 120x60 advert, but then at times it picks a random photo thumbnail displayed below the photo too.

Comment: Just made a test post via Graph API Explorer, using the first bit.ly-link you posted – shows up on my timeline with the BMW picture as shown in debug tool, looks all fine.

Comment: @CBroe WTF! Works in API Explorer for me too with a new link. something weird is going on.

Comment: @CBroe I've updated the link as for some reason, that previous one started working. The new one provides an image error regarding size, even though the photo size is over 200x200

Comment: Don’t see any warning about image size: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F1b8Mgbe

Comment: @CBroe Weird, it was there when I initially tested. I'm lost on this one. I've just posted another new photo, and the debugger says its all good, but the thumbnail still doesn't show properly. It's picked out a different random image from the page. Could there be something to do with the facebook app that allows the sharing?

Comment: No, this shouldn’t depend on the app used – the API is the same for all after all. Could you test it again using the Graph API Explorer – and post it once using the GAE app, and once your own? If that still gives different results, you should file a bug report with FB.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry for the delay (uber busy). GAE returned the correct thumb, while posting via my api didn't work. I wonder if it may be because i'm still using fb php api 2

Comment: Nope, that didn't make a bit of a difference. So, now using api 3.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing your query with the facebook Graph API Explorer worked fine for me.
You could try to add the additional parameter 'picture' to your post and place the link to your image in it.

So facebook is forced to use this as image in the post.

```
$result = $facebook->api(
            '/me/feed/',
            'post',
            array('access_token' => $token, 'message' => str_replace($link,'',$msg), 'link' => $link, 'picture' => 'http://images.ephotozine.com/gallery/2011/49/normal/52194_1323334048.jpg')
    );
```

Comment: I've done this as a temp fix, but ideally, facebook needs to pic up on my og:image meta tag

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.

Go to Facebook Object Debugger, verify every issue pointed there, fix them all. This solved my problem.

http://goo.gl/ASBsAa

Comment: Debugger comes up with no issues.

Comment: First time I've looked, it came back with quite a few. Today it showed only this warning: http://prntscr.com/1ta5dz

BUT, it rendered the image correctly when I've made a test with the link: http://prntscr.com/1ta4xx

Answer (score 1):

Reading through all the comments here, I think what's happened is the following.
Let me know how close I got. This is a shot in the dark. ;)

The first time you shared a URL to Facebook, the og:image wasn't set up perfectly, and Facebook selected a random image on the page, and cached it.

You then fixed the og:image tag, and tried to check the same URL.. FB then regurgitated the cached image.

I tried with both your links just now, and everything seems fine.

:{D

Comment: Just had the same terrible experience. Seems FB caches things that it is not suppose to cache!

Answer (score 0):

Just be patient. Facebook needs some time to crawl this image. It will not immediately show up in Facebook. If your image is not showing up in some days, just drop a note here.

Comment: It's the case that it picks a different image.

Comment: I don't see any (image related) warning in the debugger for his sample URL:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ephotozine.com%2Fuser%2Fdavidburleson-52194%2Fgallery%2Fphoto%2Foldschool-3-series-bmw-27191481

Comment: @Igy Thats right, so I don't understand why its not picking up the right photos. I'm passing a large enough photo as debugger says so.

Comment: @Igy I've even gone and added the rest of the og information. Still not working. Driving me nuts!

Comment: Works fine for me now – when I paste the URL into the Facebook message box, the preview shows up including the image.

Comment: @CBroe That's fine, but if I share the link via the facebook api for php, it doesn't show up. It randomly picks a photo instead of using the link's og:image

Comment: Works fine when shared using `FB.ui` with `method:"feed"` as well. So show your code that you use to share it via API please. (Not here in comments, update question please.)

Comment: @CBroe example added.

Answer (score 0):

Much testing and trying other bulk uploaders etc.  Finally just decided to email facebook with details and screnshot.  next day the issue has been resolved.  So, make sure to try that from the help email through your facebook account.  worked for me.